# Is there a way to only have the OK button in a JOptionPane showInputDialog (and no CANCEL button)?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, jdialog

I've seen that this is possible in other types of dialog windows such as "showConfirmDialog", where one can specify the amount of buttons and their names; but is this same functionality achievable when using "showInputDialog"? I couldn't seem to find this type of thing in the API. Perhaps I just missed it, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes it is possible. With the showOptionDialog, you can tailor the option pane much more freely. Edit: as @Maroun shows you in his answer. 1+ to his answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just add a custom JPanel as a message to `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog()`:

[image]

```
String[] options = {"OK"};
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Enter Your name: ");
JTextField txt = new JTextField(10);
panel.add(lbl);
panel.add(txt);
int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "The Title", JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options , options[0]);

if(selectedOption == 0)
{
    String text = txt.getText();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It should be "your name" BTW ;)

Answer (score 4):

`JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` returns the string the user has entered if the user clicks "OK" and returns `null` otherwise. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Returns: user's input, or null meaning the user canceled the input

You can't do this using `showInputDialog()`

However, you can use [JOptionPane#showOptionDialog()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29):

```
Object[] buttons = {"OK"};
int res = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(yourFrame,
                   "YourMessage","YourTitle",
                   JOptionPane....,
                   JOptionPane..., null, buttons , buttons[0]);
```

As @HovercraftFullOfEels stated on the comments, you can add `JTextField` to the dialog and achieve this.

Comment: Yep, this way is very flexible. 1+

Comment: I'm kind of new to Java, how do I get the user-input using this method?

Comment: No, `showOptionDialog` is something different from `showInputDialog`!

Comment: @Eng.Fouad : yes, is there a way to do this and still have the box for user-input?

Comment: You can add a JTextField or a JPanel with a JTextField to this dialog with ease. So this solution is still very much a valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Eggs are not supposed to be green.");
```

I found in [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)